# PHP Regex - match attribute and value in string

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of possible attributes:

```
$attributes = ['color','size'];
```

Part of my URL looks like this:

```
color-light-grey-size-xs
```

I would need to get an array of attributes and their values, ie:

```
$values = [
    'color' => 'light-grey',
    'size' => 'xs'
]
```

Is that doable with regex?

Comment: Are you generating the url? Where do the values come from? Answer them two and you won't need regex.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the URL. Basically, I have products with different attributes (there might be many more than just two), and I'm trying to make the pretty urls and preselect the attributes on product page based on the URL.

Comment: Ill rephrase. Goto the source of the data, dont try and reparse the url after the fact, you already have the data use it to populate your "attributes".

Comment: is the order of attributes always strict? Post the actual url sample

Comment: Imagine I have a product with URL `example.com/product/fancy-product`. The product has variable number of attributes, that you can select on the product page. I need to have an URL, that preselects the attributes on the product page, ie `example.com/product/fancy-product/color-light-grey-size-xs`. As said, the number of attributes will be different for each product

Comment: at first, consider adding a custom delimiter between attributes: after each attribute/value pair, like `example.com/product/fancy-product/color-light-grey@size-xs@`. This will make your further processing much easier

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yup, I know this would make it easier with just using explode, but I was trying to make the urls as pretty as possible

Comment: @user1049961: You have a design problem, not a regex problem. Make a better design, don't try to solve the problem using a regex or any other stupid approach. Pull the problem out by the roots.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The problem is solved, not sure what you mean by design problem. I think the URLs look great, and the regex by revo works great as well.

Comment: @user1049961: nothing more than that: if you produce these urls, you have already an access to the raw data and you don't need to parse anything to retrieve them. The fact you want to parse the url is a symptom of a bad design in your apps. Even if you are happy with your "working answer", I don't think it is the way to go. It is more and less what Lawrence Cherone tried to explain. The main problem isn't the one you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Casimir Well, I need this for a plugin that extends already existing eshop solution. My question was about regex, afaik completely valid, and I did get a cool solution. I don't see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Regular Expression which you have to feed its cluster of attributes ORed:

```
(\w++)(?>-(\w+-?(?(?!color|size)(?-1))*))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ruhmGb/1)

PHP code:

```
$str = "color-light-grey-test-size-xs";
$attrs = ['color', 'size'];

$array = [];
preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\w++)(?>-(\w+-?(?(?!" . implode("|", $attrs) . ")(?-1))*))/",
    function($matches) use (&$array) {
        $array[$matches[1]] = rtrim($matches[2], '-');
    },
    $str
);

print_r($array);
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/MVcdB)

*Note: Order is not important at all.*

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you something.

ONLY if you know that first value is `color` and second value is `size` you can match between it like:

```
\bcolor\-([\w\d\-]+)-size-([\w\d\-]+)\b
```

You will get array of 2 matches for color `$1` and for size `$2`

BUT if you don't know how your URL will look, you are in big problem.

You must know what you expect for all URL's and made matches for every combination.

Here is live example: https://regex101.com/r/3daBXx/1